# CodeIgniter-bcrypt: Login Process

Tags: php, codeigniter, bcrypt

I'm using CodeIgniter-bcrypt for my login form and running into a wall, which I hope someone can shed some light on.

In my controller, I have the following to store the password as a hash, per instructions:

```
$parent_password = $this->bcrypt->hash_password('parent_password');
```

In the login form, I have the following code (right now, for testing purposes, I'm just using the parent login for testing before passing to other users):

```
public function login_process(){
    if($this->input->post('action_type') == 'login'){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $normal_password = $this->input->post('password');
        $password = md5($normal_password);

        $remember_me = $this->input->post('remember_me');
        $user_type = $this->input->post('t');

        if($user_type == 'admin'){
            $user_info_array = $this->admins_m->get_admin_detail("admin_username = " . $this->db->escape($username) . " AND MD5(admin_password) = " . $this->db->escape($password) . "");
        }else if($user_type == 'teacher'){
            $user_info_array = $this->teachers_m->get_teacher_detail("teacher_email = " . $this->db->escape($username) . " AND teacher_password = " . $this->db->escape($password, $stored_hash) . "");
        }else{
            $user_info_array = $this->parents_m->get_parents_detail("parent_email = " . $this->db->escape($username) . " AND parent_password = " . $this->bcrypt->check_password($password, $stored_hash) . "");
        }
```

When I try to log in using the parent for testing, I'm getting a PHP error for stored_hash not being a defined variable.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the user by their username and then check the password they used to login with the one stored in the database:

```
$user = $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username')
                 ->get('users')->row();
```

if a user is returned:

```
$valid = $this->bcrypt->verify($this->input->post('password'), $user->password);
```

Comment: Hi Sean. Many thanks for the reply. I'm assuming that I will need to add these variables prior to the first "if" statement?

Comment: first you validate the users input with the validation class to check if username and password are set etc... then retrieve the user check for user/password and user type and handle accordingly